# How can I use setInterval to change state with or without useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am doing a memory game in which every time the user clicks on a card it executes *flipcard* passing the card id to it, and changes the flip status of that card, updating the *gameState*.

After a card is flipped, I want to execute *checkMatchingCards* to check if the flipped cards are of the same type, if they aren't it must flip the cards back, updating *gameState*, **BUT** after a second, not instantly.

What is the best way to assure that both functions are executed in that order, flipcard and then checkMatchingCards with the last one waiting a second?

```
const flipCard = (id) => {
  if (!canFlipCard(id)) return

  // Find card to flip
  const cardToFlip = gameState.cards.find(card => card.id === id)
  cardToFlip.isFlipped = !cardToFlip.isFlipped

  setGameState({
    ...gameState,
    cards: gameState.cards.map(card => (card.id === cardToFlip.id ? cardToFlip : card)),
    flippedCards: gameState.flippedCards.concat(cardToFlip)
  })
}

const checkMatchingCards = (cards) => {
  if (!cards) return
  const cardsMatch = cards.every(card => card.color === cards[0].color)

  // If cards match and reach number of cards to match
  if (cardsMatch && cards.length === MATCH_GOAL) {
    setGameState({
      ...gameState,
      flippedCards: [],
      matchedCards: gameState.matchedCards.concat(cards),
    })
  }
  // If cards doesn't match, clean flippedCards
  else if (!cardsMatch && cards.length >= 2) {
    setGameState({
      ...gameState,
      cards: gameState.cards.map(card => gameState.flippedCards.includes(card, 0) ? { ...card, isFlipped: false } : card),
      flippedCards: [],
    })
  }
}
```

I found two ways of doing this, one is using setTimeout so every time the game renders, it checks for matching cards,

```
setTimeout(() => {
  checkMatchingCards(gameState.flippedCards)
}, 900)
```

And another way with useEffect and setTImeout, which executes only when *flippedCards* change:

```
useEffect(()=> {
  setTimeout(() => {
    checkMatchingCards(gameState.flippedCards)
  }, 900)  
}, gameState.flippedCards)
```

I leave the entire code here, in case it helps
https://github.com/takihama/memory-game

Comment: Do you want to execute `checkMatchingCards` every time `gameState.flippedCards` changed? What is the expected behavior when `gameState.flippedCards` changes 2 times in less than 1 second? Does `checkMatchingCards` need to be executed 2 times, or just once.

Comment: The second is relative, its just to show the card flipped for an amount of time so the user can see it. In the case you mention it should run checkMatchingCards twice

Comment: If Iin the future I add a timer component, with the first option it will call checkMatchingCards on every render, every second,, but with useEffect it will do it only when flippedCards change.
But it's the only way to do it? Wait it to be rendered and then after a sec call checkMatchingCards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `useEffect` in this case.

Don't call `setTimeout` outside of `useEffect`, this will be called every time the component re-render (which isn't necessary since `checkMatchingCards` only depends on `gameState.flippedCards`).

And you should pass`useEffect` dependencies as an array

```
useEffect(()=> {
  setTimeout(() => {
    checkMatchingCards(gameState.flippedCards)
  }, 900)  
}, [gameState.flippedCards])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example that uses two states:

1. `show` is an array matching `cards.length` that keeps track of which cards have been flipped
2. `selected` is an array that keeps track of every card a player has clicked

And two effects:

1. When `show` cards changes, we determine if the player has won the game
2. When `selected` cards changes, if there is an even number of cards, a pair is compared. If they do not match, `setTimeout` hides them again

```js
function App({ cards = [] }) {
  // state for hidden/flipped cards and player selection
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(Array(cards.length).fill(false))
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([])

  // helper for toggling card state
  const toggle = key => setShow(s => updateArray(s, key, v => !v))

  // when shown cards change, determine if the player won the game
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (show.every(Boolean)) console.log(`you won in ${selected.length/2} guesses`)
  }, [show])

  // when selected cards change, determine whether they should stay flipped
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (selected.length & 1 || cards[selected[0]] == cards[selected[1]]) return
    setTimeout(_ => { toggle(selected[0]), toggle(selected[1]) }, 1000)
  }, [selected])

  // when the player clicks a hidden card, flip it and add it to the selection
  const onClick = key => event => {
    if (show[key]) return
    toggle(key), setSelected(s => [key, ...s])
  }

  // render cards
  return cards.map((c, key) =>
    <Card key={key} text={c} onClick={onClick(key)} show={show[key]} />
  )
}
```

Depends on a generic `updateArray` helper for immutably updating arrays:

```js
function updateArray(a, key, func) {
  return [...a.slice(0, key), func(a[key]), ...a.slice(key + 1)]
}
```

And a stateless `Card` component:

```js
const Card = ({ text, onClick, show }) =>
  <button type="button" onClick={onClick} children={show ? text : "?" } />
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below and try to win the game!

```js
function App({ cards = [] }) {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(Array(cards.length).fill(false))
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([])
  const toggle = key => setShow(s => updateArray(s, key, v => !v))
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (show.every(Boolean)) console.log(`you won in ${selected.length/2} guesses`)
  }, [show])
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (selected.length & 1 || cards[selected[0]] == cards[selected[1]]) return
    setTimeout(_ => { toggle(selected[0]), toggle(selected[1]) }, 1000)
  }, [selected])
  const onClick = key => event => {
    if (show[key]) return
    toggle(key), setSelected(s => [key, ...s])
  }
  return cards.map((c, key) =>
    <Card key={key} text={c} onClick={onClick(key)} show={show[key]} />
  )
}

function updateArray(a, key, func) {
  return [...a.slice(0, key), func(a[key]), ...a.slice(key + 1)]
}

const Card = ({ text, onClick, show }) =>
  <button type="button" onClick={onClick} children={show ? text : "?" } />

ReactDOM.render(
  <App cards={["⚡️", "", "", "", "⚡️", ""]} />,
  document.querySelector("#app")
)
```

```css
button { line-height: 7rem; margin: 0.25rem; font-size: 4rem; width: 5rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```